# MonkeyRunner and Dialog

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am learning MonkeyRunner tool. I have a Date and Time Picker and want to pass the values to it.

I tried using **device.Type()**. But that does not work.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the KeyEvents directly. You can find the list of KeyEvents [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

for example `device.press('KEYCODE_1', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)`